# What is the most micro-optimal and elegant "Insert in order" algorithm for IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to create a generalized "insert in order" algorithm in C#, something that would implement the following

```
/// <summary>
/// Inserts a new element in its proper order into an ordered enumeration
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The comparable type</typeparam>
/// <param name="source">The sorted enumeration</param>
/// <param name="insertion">The element to insert</param>
/// <returns>A new enumeration with <paramref name="insertion"/> in its proper order</returns>
public static IEnumerable<T> InsertInOrder<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T insertion) where T : IComparable<T>
{
      throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

and be as optimized as possible in terms of the number of operations and the memory. The main problem I'm having is that when working with `MoveNext()` there's always these cases in my algorithm where I "accidentally" might have moved one too far and want to recover the previous element. That is making it hard for me to write something that is optimal and elegant.

For elegant-looking in O(n) time and not directly using the enumereator I came up with

```
IEnumerable<T> smallers = source.TakeWhile(x => x.CompareTo(insertion) < 0);
IEnumerable<T> greaters = source.SkipWhile(x => x.CompareTo(insertion) >= 0);

IEnumerable<T> reordered = smallers.Concat(new[] { insertion }).Concat(greaters);

foreach (T element in reordered)
{
    yield return element;
}
```

but this is not efficient due to multiple enumeration on `source`.

So I tried instead to convert to single enumeration and eventually (although it's embarrassing how long it took me) came up with

```
bool inserted = false;
IEnumerator<T> mover = source.GetEnumerator();
while (mover.MoveNext())
{
    if (mover.Current.CompareTo(insertion) < 0)
    {
        yield return mover.Current;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!inserted)
        {
            yield return insertion;
            inserted = true;
        }
        yield return mover.Current;
    }
}
```

but the problem there is that once we get to the point in the list where the `insertion` is less than or equal `mover.Current`, the `if (mover.Current.CompareTo(insertion) < 0)` becomes a useless check.

So, eventually I came up with

```
bool movedNext;
IEnumerator<T> mover = source.GetEnumerator();
while (movedNext = mover.MoveNext() && mover.Current.CompareTo(insertion) < 0)
{
    yield return mover.Current;
}
yield return insertion;
if (movedNext)
{
    do
    {
        yield return mover.Current;
    } while (mover.MoveNext());
}
```

but there is still the inefficiency of having an extra variable `moveNext` and having to keep reassigning it `movedNext = mover.MoveNext()` over and over.

Is it possible to write this insertion algorithm without an extra variable to deal with the "possible extra move"? :)

Comment: That extra variable costs nothing (compared to the surrounfing code). You could fold that if/do-while but that wouldn't be a real saving, just cosmetics.

Comment: W/o intruding some sort of a buffering, whatever you do (including the accepted answer) leads to O(N^2) time complexity and  at some point , `StackOverflowException` - for instance, `var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<int>(), (r, i) => r.InsertInOrder(i)).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last bit of code is about as good as it can get. Stop worrying about insignificant inefficiencies like the extra `movedNext` variable and the assignment inside the `while` loop.

Now, if your question is simple professional curiosity on if it can be avoided? Then the answer is: Yes, of course! But (there is always a but) at a cost: *goto* enters, *readability* exits:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> InsertInOrder<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    T insertion) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            if (e.Current.CompareTo(insertion) < 0)
            {
                yield return e.Current;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return insertion;
                yield return e.Current;
                goto continueEnumerating;
            }
        }

        yield return insertion;
        goto exit;

    continueEnumerating:
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return e.Current;
        }

    exit:
        yield break;
    }
```

Methinks I'll pay the inefficiency thousandfold...

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks!